# Replacing letters in the EditText based on some rules

Tags: java, android, string, android-layout

I'm creating an application so that when user inputs a word and presses the button, the `TextView` shows a new word based on some rules. Like if the word has letter "a" in it, then change it with ".-"(Morse code).

Example: input word: "abba"   output: ".--....--..." ( a=".-" b="-...")

I have created a demo app with just 2 rules for "a" and "b". It works if I input just one letter but when I input more like "ab" it doesn't behave correctly.

Java file:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText vpis;
TextView rezultat;
Button pretvori;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vpis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tekst);
    rezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultat);
    pretvori = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gumb);


    pretvori.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String morse = vpis.getText().toString();
            for (int i=0; i<morse.length(); i++){
                if(morse.charAt(i) == 'a'){
                    rezultat.setText(".-");
                }else if (morse.charAt(i) == 'b'){
                    rezultat.setText("-...");
                }
            }
        }
    });
}
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: you can use regex for this or string replace method much easier and you can do it without for loop

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a faulty logic - you're always overriding the text by using `setText()` every time and that's why only the last value is visible in the `TextView`. You need to append your result and at the end of the loop, set the text to your `TextView`. Do this:

```
String morse = vpis.getText().toString();
String text = "";
        for (int i=0; i<morse.length(); i++){
            if(morse.charAt(i) == 'a'){
                text+=".-";
            }else if (morse.charAt(i) == 'b'){
                text+="-...";
            }
     }
rezultat.setText(text);
```

If you want to have slightly better performance, consider using [StringBuilder](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuilder.html) [StringBuffer](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/StringBuffer.html) instead of String since `Strings` are **immutable** and concatenation actually makes a new `String` each time.
With a StringBuilder it'd look like this:

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
```

Instead of `text+= whatever`, you'd use `sb.append(whatever)` and you'd finally do `rezultat.setText(sb.toString());`

Answer (score 0):

this can be done by string replace method as what I comment it is the most easiest way and dont take more ram usage. Here is the modified code from what you have

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

EditText vpis;
TextView rezultat;
Button pretvori;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    vpis = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.tekst);
    rezultat = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.rezultat);
    pretvori = (Button) findViewById(R.id.gumb);


    pretvori.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String morse = vpis.getText().toString();
            String newString = morse.replace("a",".-");
            newString = newString.replace("b","-...");
            rezultat.setText(newString);
        }
    });
}
}
```

If you have many pattern then you can make the pattern a constant array and just loop the pattern with string replace method.

**Correction:**

In your example the "abba" should return ".--...-....-" like this.